# Prevent MacBook Pro from sleeping when the lid is closed and the AC adapter is being unplugged

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, power-management, external-display

My MacBook Pro is connected to two external monitors using a docking station. The internal screen lid is constantly closed and I don't usually use it. I only use the external screens.

The problem is that whenever I disconnect the power adapter (while the lid is closed), it triggers a sleeping mode. Therefore I can't unplug the AC adapter and keep working. I would like to prevent my computer from sleeping when the lid is closed and the power is unplugged. Did anyone face this issue and found a solution?

**Additional Details:**

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Remark**

Before I opened this thread I found this similar question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261784/how-to-prevent-screen-lock-when-macbook-ac-adapter-is-unplugged. However, the solution there does not fit my needs, as it prevents the computer from sleeping at all (which is not my intention).

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Terminal.app
2. Type in the command `sudo pmset disablesleep 1`
3. Enter your password to authorize the change to the power management settings.

Note:
Tested with m1 macbook air, but it should work on other models as well,
and you can run `sudo pmset disablesleep 0` to restore setting

---

Source: https://developerinsider.co/prevent-external-monitor-to-sleep-when-macbook-ac-adapter-unplugged

Comment: Wouldn't it prevent mac from sleeping entirely?
I am looking for a solution in which the computer still gets asleep after x minutes of idle

Comment: AFAIK, yes. Maybe try use ifttt or shortcut to trigger `disablesleep 0` on screen saver shows and trigger `disablesleep 1` when unlocked, just a quick thought not tested

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the Apple icon in the upper left corner.
2. Click System Preferences.
3. Click Battery.
4. Click Power Adapter.
5. Click the slider and move it to Never.
6. Click the Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off check box.

---

Source: https://www.lifewire.com/prevent-macbook-from-sleeping-when-lid-is-closed-5203069

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it does not work. The moment I unplug the power adapter - both external monitors turn off and the Mac gets locked. Even if I press keyboard keys and move the mouse around they won't turn back on. In addition, this solution has an undesired side effect: when the power adapter is plugged and the computer is idle, it will never go to sleep and the monitors will be kept on.

Comment: this does NOT work anymore, these kind of answers should disappear from the internet

Answer (score 0):

You could use the free [Amphetamine](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704) app to keep your computer awake for a specified amount of time, or while a specified app is running.

Comment: So this means there's no native way to keep a MacBook running while connected to an external monitor, lid closed, and unplugged from an AC power source. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's correct, as far as I know.

Comment: No, it's wrong. Lid closed will bring it to sleep even with this app